# Access VBA: How do I make the VBA editor stop auto-filling values?

Tags: vba, ms-access, syntax, ms-access-2013

I already turned off auto-syntax check but this problem still persists. Whenever I try to modify a time, let's say from `08:30:00 AM` to `08:30:05 AM`, Access sometimes fills in a zero after I backspace to clear the `0`. It forces me to have to quickly change the value otherwise it gives me an annoying pop up message saying syntax error....but the editor caused the error, not me!

How do I fix this? Please help me fix this.

Comment: Doesn't access wait until you submit your correction with pressing Enter?

Comment: I think you're thinking of what happens *after* the error message pops up. All I can do there is press enter, make the fix, and then reset. Yes, it "waits for me". But I'm asking about inline code fixing while the procedure is **not** paused. It tries to guess a value for a time *while I'm typing* which causes an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens when code is running, which forces Access to constantly compile the VBA source code.

Typical example: a form is open that uses the `OnTimer` Event (has `TimerInterval` > 0).

To prevent this: Close all forms while editing code (Design view is ok).

If it's not forms, press the "Stop" button in the VBA toolbar (the blue square) to stop all running code.

Comment: Ah, yes that makes sense. This is code for a form timer event that has an interval set to 1000ms....